# Drawing piechart in HTML email using Apache Commons Email

Tags: java, email, html-email, apache-commons

I would want to send statistical information to my clients showing the number of transactions processed on every terminal or branch. I am using Apache Commons Email to send HTML emails. 
I would like to send a pie-chart data like [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) one on the site. 
My java code is basic extracted [from](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=btpka3.github.com-master/java/my-mail/src/test/java/me/test/TestEmail.java).

It goes like:

```
public void testHtmlEmailPiechart() 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, EmailException, MalformedURLException { 
        HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail(); 
        email.setHostName(emailServer); 
        email.setSmtpPort(587); 
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true); 
        email.setAuthentication(userName, password); 
        email.setCharset(emailEncoding); 

        email.addTo(receiver, "Mwesigye John Bosco"); 
        email.setFrom(userName, "Enovate system emailing alert"); 
        email.setSubject("Conkev aml Engine Statistics"); 

        URL url = new URL("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROXe8tn1ljtctM53TkLJhLs6gEX56CvL0shvyq1V6wg7tXUDH8KRyVP30"); 
//        URL url = new URL("http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif"); 
        String cid2 = email.embed(url, "logo.gif"); 

        email.setHtmlMsg("<html>\n" +
"  <head>\n" +
"    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js\"></script>\n" +
"    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
"      google.charts.load(\"current\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});\n" +
"      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);\n" +
"      function drawChart() {\n" +
"        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([\n" +
"          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],\n" +
"          ['Work',     11],\n" +
"          ['Eat',      2],\n" +
"          ['Commute',  2],\n" +
"          ['Watch TV', 2],\n" +
"          ['Sleep',    7]\n" +
"        ]);\n" +
"\n" +
"        var options = {\n" +
"          title: 'My Daily Activities',\n" +
"          is3D: true,\n" +
"        };\n" +
"\n" +
"        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));\n" +
"        chart.draw(data, options);\n" +
"      }\n" +
"    </script>\n" +
"  </head>\n" +
"  <body>\n" +
"    <div id=\"piechart_3d\" style=\"width: 900px; height: 500px;\">Piechart Data</div>\n" +
"  </body>\n" +
"</html>"); 
        email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages"); 

        email.send(); 
    }
```

My guess is that the JavaScript is not recognized because the code works like sending images,styling fonts and I have sent to my email address some sample mail.  I would like your help or recommendation of any material I can read to achieve this as long  as am using Java.The processes is automated running in the background so no user interface is involved. 
Thanks.